# Images not loading when building angular application for production

Tags: c#, html, css, angular, visual-studio

So i have an angular app that when served locally works fine and all the images correctly load. However when i build the application for production using ng build --prod and then run it within visual studio the images are not found. I am guessing it has something to do with how the angular assets folder is being compiled. All images are stored within assets > images and then accessed like this:

```
<img src="assets/images/buying.png" class="card-img-top" alt="photo">
```

Within visual studio the bundle config looks as follows:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
        //            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        //// Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        //// ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
        //            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
        //          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
        //          "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        //bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
        //          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
        //          "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Bundles").Include(
                   "~/bundles/runtime-es5.*",
                   "~/bundles/runtime-es2015.*",
                   "~/bundles/polyfills-es5.*",
                   "~/bundles/polyfills-es2015.*",
                   "~/bundles/main-es5.*",
                   "~/bundles/main-es2015.*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles").Include("~/bundles/styles.*"));
    }
}
```

html that integrates the angular app:

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "InfoTestAngular";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>angular app</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles")
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <app-root></app-root>
        </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles")
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* curator-feed-default-layout */
    (function () {
        var i, e, d = document, s = "script"; i = d.createElement("script"); i.async = 1;
        i.src = "https://cdn.curator.io/published/ccc71ec0-ceff-435f-9343-7e5d29f5b570.js";
        e = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; e.parentNode.insertBefore(i, e);
    })();
    </script>
</html>
```

expected result when run locally via the angular cli:

[image]

When run in visual studio:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your image address is like this:

http://localhost:100/assets/images/buying.png

add ( / ) to src of image tag to show it in other address like this
http://localhost:100/home/infoTest

```
<img src="/assets/images/buying.png" class="card-img-top" alt="photo">
```

Comment: That don't work. It has to do with how angular is compiling the bundles.